# Script running other code it shouldnt

Tags: php

I have spent the last couple of hours trying to get my sessions to work, the problem I am having is that I have this session check, which runs on page open, it all works fine etc...
 However, when the user clicks submit on the page, it also runs the same session check as well, causing the page to throw an error.

Here is the session check:

```
$estate_id="";

if (isset($_SESSION['addon_estate_id'])) {
    $estate_id = $_SESSION['addon_estate_id'];
    unset($_SESSION['addon_estate_id']);
} else {         
    $reg_error = "You need to select a house first.";
    $_SESSION['error'] = $reg_error;
    header("Location: addons.php");
    exit;    
}
```

Here is the code that runs on user clicking a submit button:

```
if (isset($_POST['add_browse_submit'])) {        
    $addon_selected_id = $_POST['addon_hidden_id'];
    $addon_hidden_estate_id = $_POST['addon_hidden_estate_id'];

    $_SESSION['addon_sess_id'] = $addon_selected_id;
    $_SESSION['addon_estate_detail_id'] = $addon_hidden_estate_id;

    header('Location: addon_detail.php');
    exit;
}
```

Basically what is happening is when the user clicks the submit button, it also runs the `session check` code, causing the `reg_error`. If I comment out the code in the `else` in session check, then all is good and the script goes to `addon_detail.php` as it should.

Any reason why it is doing this?

Thanks

Comment: well are they on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your post handling code is below the session check. If you move the post check above and then make sure that code is actually setting the `$_SESSION['addon_estate_id']` then it won't error.

That assumes this is your goal. I would have assumed you would set the `$_SESSION['addon_estate_id']` in the example, but who can tell?

Comment: The `$_SESSION['addon_estate_id']` is set in a previous page, which then loads this current page, it is a bit confusing :) Thanks for your answer though i will look now

Comment: Hi, ok i moved the submit button code above and it worked great, what i don't understand is why it was running the session check again, i thought when a user clicked submit, it would only run the code inside the submit if isset?

Comment: it makes perfect sense. you say if isset post. that post var is only set when the user submits it. However, your session check says if isset session ELSE. So when not set, trigger the error. makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The first visit to the page (assuming the user already has `$_SESSION['addon_estate_id']` set, will clear that variable and store it in `$estate_id`. The second visit (after submitting the form) sees that `$_SESSION['addon_estate_id']` is not set, so it throws an error.

You aren't referencing `$estate_id` in the second block, so maybe you don't need it? Is there a reason you unset it on the first page visit?